# Place item at specific position in dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

Can we place/keep dropdownlist item at particular position. Say for example I want to bind dropdownlist to datasource and then add new item which is placed at particular position in dropdownlist. How can this be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Insert method.

```
dropDownList.Items.Insert(index, new ListItem("Default Panel", "0"));
```